# How to loop query in pyathena?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-athena, pyathena

I am using pyathena library to query schemas and storing it in pandas dataframe. I've a list which contains atleast 30,000 items.

eg. l1 = [1,2,3,4..... 29999,30000]

Now I want to pass this list items in sql query. Since I cannot pass all 30,000 list items at a time, therefore, I divided list into 30 chunks and passing each chunk in loop, as shown below:

Note: I tried it to divide it in fewer chunks but 1000 items per chunks seems best option.

```
#function to divide list into chunks
def divide_chunks(l, n): 

    # looping till length l 
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n] 

# How many elements each list should have 
n = 1000
x = list(divide_chunks(l1, n))
#x is list, which will have 30 sets of sub-list of l1

count = 0

while count<len(x):
#converting sub-list to string, so that it can be passed in sql query
    y = str(x[count]).replace("[","").replace("]","")

    queryResult = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from abc where col1 IN (y), conn)
    #appending query result to final pandas dataframe
    finalResult= finalResult.append(queryResult)
    count+=1
```

In first iteration it works fine but for remaining iteration I'am getting below error:
(sometimes it goes to 2nd and 3rd iteration also but not more than that)

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1594             else:
-> 1595                 cur.execute(*args)
   1596             return cur

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyathena\util.py in _wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     27         with _lock:
---> 28             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     29     return _wrapper

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyathena\cursor.py in execute(self, operation, parameters, work_group, s3_staging_dir)
     54         else:
---> 55             raise OperationalError(query_execution.state_change_reason)
     56         return self

OperationalError: Query exhausted resources at this scale factor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotSupportedError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1598             try:
-> 1599                 self.con.rollback()
   1600             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyathena\connection.py in rollback(self)
    141     def rollback(self):
--> 142         raise NotSupportedError

NotSupportedError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-90403d399324> in <module>
    290 start = time.localtime()
    291 
--> 292 weuData()
    293 #print(weuResult)
    294 naData()

<ipython-input-39-90403d399324> in weuData()
    127 
    128 
--> 129         queryResult = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from abc where col1 IN("+y+")", conn2)
    130       finalResult= finalResult.append(queryResult)

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    408             coerce_float=coerce_float,
    409             parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 410             chunksize=chunksize,
    411         )
    412 

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1643 
   1644         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 1645         cursor = self.execute(*args)
   1646         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1647 

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1603                     "to rollback".format(sql=args[0], exc=exc)
   1604                 )
-> 1605                 raise_with_traceback(ex)
   1606 
   1607             ex = DatabaseError(

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
     42     if traceback == Ellipsis:
     43         _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
---> 44     raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
     45 
     46 

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1597         except Exception as exc:
   1598             try:
-> 1599                 self.con.rollback()
   1600             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
   1601                 ex = DatabaseError(

c:\users\my_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyathena\connection.py in rollback(self)
    140 
    141     def rollback(self):
--> 142         raise NotSupportedError

Execution failed on sql: SELECT * from abc where col1 IN (1001,1002.......2000)
Query exhausted resources at this scale factor
unable to rollback
```

Comment: create a temporary table with the 30,000 values and with a single join you can process everything in a single step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def divide_chunks(l, n): 

        # looping till length l 
        for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
            yield l[i:i + n] 
n = 20000

x = list(divide_chunks(l1, n)) 
count = 0
while count<len(x):

    y = str(x[count]).replace("[","").replace("]","")
    print("Iteration number: ",count)



    data = cursor.execute("SELECT * from abc where col1 IN"+ (y))
    data2 = data.fetchall()
    data3 = data2 + data1
    count+=1

#add your all data3(list) in dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=['col1','col2'...])
```

Still there might be the possibility that query will show *Query exhausted*